# Ants model extension in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to modify ants model in such a way that when an ant reaches a food source for the first time, that time tick is recorded for every ant individually, also number of rounds for each ant to all three food sources, i have introduced variable t as turtles own. can anyone help e with it please

Answer (score 1):

First, t is a fairly uninformative variable name. I know it is the standard symbol for time, but you really want time-found-food or whatever, because t doesn't tell you what time is remembered. Sticking with your variable name, first you need to find the piece of code where the ant finds food and add something like `set t ticks`.